# How to catch user cancel in Companion Device Pairing screen?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

In Android 8.0 and above, we may use the CompainonDeviceManager to pair out app with a bluetooth or wifi device. The [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing) tells us how to handle:

- The happy path (i.e. the user selects a device from the presented list)
- Pairing failure (e.g. no devices found, the request times out)

What the documentation does not tell is how to catch the case where the companion device scan is successful and presents one or more devices to the user, but the user cancels the pairing.

How can I catch the negative result of a user pressing Cancel in the Companion Device Pairing screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is not too late! I was wondering the same thing. It turns out that the documentations tells you to include the following in the `onActivityResult()` method:

```
if (requestCode == SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
     // User has chosen to pair with the Bluetooth device.
     BluetoothDevice deviceToPair = data.getParcelableExtra(CompanionDeviceManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
}
```

Notice that the code also checks if `resultCode` is equal to `RESULT_OK`. By checking for this separately you can catch the "Cancel" click, like this:

```
if (requestCode == SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // user has selected a device                   
                BluetoothDevice device = data.getParcelableExtra(CompanionDeviceManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            } else {
                // cancel handled here
            }
}
```

Comment: I cannot verify this at the moment, but presume it is correct. Good advice!